# Git issue about private projects github

Tags: git, github

I worked at a IT company in Brazil for 6 months and my contract agreement ended. A few days ago I was removed from a private repository and all the commit history on my profile was removed. I want to know if there is anything that I can do to stay out of this private repository, but still show the commits on my profile. I'm just a intern and my GitHub profile has nothing to show to my future employers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - some time ago GitHub introduced the option to include commits to private repositories in your contributions graphs:. You can access this by clicking on "Contribution settings" on the right of your contributions graph when viewing your profile:

[image: Contributions dropdown]

This will also include lines like the following in your activity log:

[image: Activity entries]